# How to call function based on argparse using selective structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, argparse

I'm new on python and I was wondering how to call a function based on argparse on a selective structure

I tried this function

```py
def parseArgument(abv, name, hdescriptop, isrequired):
  parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument(abv, 
                      name, 
                      help=hdescription, 
                      required=isrequired,
                      action="store_true",
                      )
  args=parser.parse_args()
  return args

parseArgument("-y", "--humedity", "Calculate humedity", False)

if args.cycle:
  print("DPV cycle: ", DPV(w, 0, list_DPV_CYCLE, count_NC))
#elif args.moredata:
#  print(more data)
```

*Tip: there's no need to know what does DPV

I expect when I run the python script on the terminal and write 
`python nameofthescript.py -y`, get the called function parseArgument() with the selective structure

Comment: Don't set the `required` parameter when using `store_true`.  `parseArgument` returns an `args` variable; the calling code should save it; eg.. `args = parseArgument(...)`.  When debugging add a `print(args)`.  Why do you expect a `args.circle` attribute?  You don't define a `circle` argument.

Comment: @hpaulj you are right. ```args.cicle``` was working for me when I use without making it a function ```parser.add_argument('-c','--cycle', action="store_true", help="show cycle data")```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on my comment:

```
In [50]: def parseArgument(argv, abv, name, hdes): 
    ...:   parser=argparse.ArgumentParser() 
    ...:   parser.add_argument(abv,  
    ...:                       name,  
    ...:                       help=hdes,  
    ...:                       action="store_true", 
    ...:                       ) 
    ...:   args=parser.parse_args(argv) 
    ...:   return args 
    ...:  
    ...: args = parseArgument([], "-y", "--humedity", "Calculate humedity")                                     
In [51]: args                                                                                                   
Out[51]: Namespace(humedity=False)
In [52]: args.humedity                                                                                          
Out[52]: False
```

test a different commandline:

```
In [53]: args = parseArgument(['-y'], "-y", "--humedity", "Calculate humedity")                                 
In [54]: args                                                                                                   
Out[54]: Namespace(humedity=True)
In [55]: args.humedity                                                                                          
Out[55]: True
```